# How can I animate multiple properties of the same object at once?

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to animate a vehicle coming to a stop and I want the tail lights to start glowing at a certain point. To have a realistic effect, I was using the compositing screen layout with more than 10 nodes and about 30 values and checkboxes. So, I was wondering if there is a way to keyframe all these values at once instead of clicking on each value and insert a keyframe.

Comment: Although I have not done this many personally, I am aware that this type of thing is handled using drivers. [Here is a tutorial I found.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMoBFzXFAUM) and some [documentation on Blender manuals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html). Hope this helps to get you on the right track.

Comment: Python is generally how you perform an operation many times at once. Computers are great at this kind of stuff - people aren't.

Comment: @farhat2 I think you misplaced the animation nodes tag, maybe you want to have them separated as `animation` and `nodes`, because `animation nodes` is a (great) addon and your question doesn't ask anything about it. But if you want there is a way to answer the question using the animation nodes so I'll put it as answer for now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cycles Material Output](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/material/cycles_material_output.html) node to control the strength of your emission shader where its value is controlled through an [Animate Float](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/animation/animate_float.html) node.

[image: Node Tree]

Where the *Delay* node controls the frame at which the animation will start.